# Is it possible to set selfHeal on an ArgoCD cluster level when using applicationSet

Tags: argocd

So I have an argocd bootstrap app with an applicationSet. In the documentation https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/auto_sync/ I want to use selfHeal option to automatically sync any changes made on live clusters. However setting this option in applicationSet means that this option will be affecting each app in each cluster. Is there a way to set this at least on a cluster level?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's currently impossible because the selfHeal option awaits a boolean, and you cannot have it as a parameter with Go template.

You can see here the progress regarding this issue https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/11213